# editing PDFs (find and replace '&nbsp;')

Tags: linux, windows-xp, pdf, text-editors, find-and-replace

What method/program could I use to perform a find and replace to turn `'&nbsp;'` into `' '` in a PDF file?

I can use either linux or windows solution.

EDIT:

The addon for OpenOffice Draw to access PDFs does replace `&nbsp` characters with regular spaces when re-exported as a PDF (find and replace tool doesn't work), however OODraw breaks the PDF formatting (font type / formatting). I'm thinking a programmatic-solution may be needed (something usable from the command line to find and replace.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use openoffice (along with Oracle's PDF Import extension) to edit the PDF and then do a find and replace all

Comment: +1 (partial) Opening the file shows it only as plain text. It doesn't see the `&nbsp;` code in the text when I perform a find and replace. Opening the file and re-exporting it as a PDF DOES replace it, however formatting is broken so some text and sections overlap, which isn't easily fixable as this is a PDF output from a vendor made in Publisher with multi-columns and non-standard font (no idea what font was used).